# Variable quoting difference between bash 4.3.43 and 4.4.19

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-coreutils

Out of curiosity I wonder which change in bash (or head?) made this the following behaviour change,

In 4.4.19 we have the following behaviour,

```
# Assign "foo <new line> bar" to variabe 'var'
$ > var="foo
bar"

# Echo with and without quotes,
$ > echo "${var}"
foo
bar

$ > echo ${var} 
foo bar

# Read all lines (1) except the last, 
$ > head -1 <<< ${var}
foo 

$ > head -1 <<< "${var}"
foo
```

Doing the exact same thing in bash 4.2.46 and 4.3.43 results in different output when reading the variable with head.

```
# Assign "foo <new line> bar" to variabe 'var'
$ > var="foo
bar"

# Echo with and without quotes,
$ > echo "${var}"
foo
bar

$ > echo ${var} 
foo bar

$ > head -1 <<< ${var}
foo bar

$ > head -1 <<< "${var}"
foo
```

So it seems to me (with 4.4.19) that no matter if you quote the variable or not, head's input will be both lines. And with versions 4.2.46 and 4.3.43 the input actually differs depending on if you quote the variable or not.

The earlier behaviour makes sense to me, where you would have to quote the variable if you want the new line. I'm genuinely interested in this behaviour change and the reasoning behind it. I tried looking through the bash-changelog, but nothing obvious stood out to me that would lead to this change (although I have some very vague feeling that I've stumbled on this before).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164110/why-is-a-here-string-command-substitution-considered-as-a-single-line - chang in Bash here-string word splitting behaviour between 4.4-alpha and 4.4-beta.

Comment: Thanks for finding this for me!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior in bash 4.3 is a bug which is fixed in 4.4. See the [original bug report](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2015-09/msg00022.html) and
 [Chet's reply](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2015-09/msg00035.html) (2015/09).

And the most recent posts to bash mailing list regarding this: [the question](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-11/msg00099.html) and [Chet's reply](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-11/msg00104.html) (2017/11).